# Spring on docker, environment variables not evaluated with configuration placeholders

Tags: spring, docker, environment-variables, yaml, docker-compose

I have a Spring project and use an application.yml file to run configure it. When using placeholders in the configuration file and run it as a built docker image it will not evaluate the placeholder, whereas this works fine when running the jar without docker. What could be wrong here?

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "${POSTGRES_DB_USER}"
```

application.yml

```
server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
  context-path: /
  port: 8085

logging:
  config: config/log4j2-spring.xml

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:./data/cdr
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop

security:
  user:
    password: secretpassword

---

spring:
  profiles: docker
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/databasename
    username: ${POSTGRES_DB_USER}
    password: ${POSTGRES_DB_PASS}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  application:
    image: domain.com:3000/application:0-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - application:/application/logs
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      PASSWORD: secretpassword
  postgres:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.5-2
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      DB_NAME: databasename
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASS: secretpassword

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
  application-logs:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Does your `application` image have `ENV POSTGRES_DB_USER` etc. defined in the Dockerfile? Environment variables are not persisted in image layers unless they're explicitly set with `ENV`.

Comment: Thanks I have to look into that, but right now it seem like the placeholders are broken when running the jar from the terminal as well, trying to create a bare bone Spring project now to confirm this. Maybe placeholders will not work when using YAML files instead of .properties files? The documentation is a but vague This is so confusing for a Spring beginner like me.

Comment: And by the way as I understood this that if I on the postgres service set a variable named DB_USER (as above) it should be accessible as POSTGRES_DB_USER (all environment variables get the service name in uppsercase as prefix) in any container that has the postgres service linked, is that not so?

Comment: Yes, but [container links are considered legacy functionality](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). Using explicit environment variables and Docker networks is much cleaner & safer.

Comment: > is that not so?
It is not so, you're confusing the deprecated link environment variables with the `environment` field. see https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: @EltonStoneman Thanks for the heads up, it seem like a lot more to take in, a bit sad that it needs to be this complicated but I guess I'll learn in time. Think I will have to start with legacy links though until I get the basic setup working with a few services communicating with each other. Great with the guidance anyway.

Comment: @dnephin thanks! oh my, there seem to be even more to consider here. I'm hoping for a condensed 15 minute guide on how to do this, maybe I'll write one once I learn how to do this, right now it's more of googling and trying to put parts from various blog posts and documentation pages together in the hope of finally getting something working.

Comment: Compose does have a getting started guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/ , I've added an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  application:
    image: domain.com:3000/application:0-SNAPSHOT
    volumes:
      - application-logs:/application/logs
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB_PASS: secretpassword
  postgres:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.5-2
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql
    environment:
      DB_NAME: databasename
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASS: secretpassword

volumes:
  postgres-data: {}
  application-logs: {}
```